# Why use useStyles MaterialUI function instead of CSS?

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm making a MERN app using Material UI components or inline attributes. But why create a js file, where I have to import the makeStyles function, which basically returns an object with CSS. And then assign it to the classNames of my different elements accordingly.
When I can make a CSS file, and write the CSS directly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the benefits of using [CSS in JS](https://cssinjs.org/features) or something similar, just like the way your are writing CSS with Material UI is that you could make the CSS property **dynamic**. Meaning that the CSS property could adapt to any dynamic data on your App.

Imagine you are creating a fade-in effect for some cards to pop up, and you want it happens in the following way:

- It will always be 1 seconds for all the cards to show up, from the beginning till the end.
- There will be a equal time for each card to fade-in.
- After the former card finished its fade-in animation, the next card will start the fade-in animation (that means the latter card should have the animation delay of the card's animation duration).

If you have two cards in total, maybe you could simple write the CSS aniamtion-duration of 0.5s, and 0.5 animation-delay for the second card.

But what if you don't know the total number of cards? That's what we called a dynamic data. We could not make a static CSS property to complete such animation. With CSS alone and no help from HTML & JS, there's no way of doing that. With JS, we have the ability to access the variable and dynamic data, that could also be applied into CSS, so we could put them into the CSS.

CSS in JS is not the only way but an efficient tool to achieve that, that's why there are many packages out there to use it, for example [Styled Component](https://styled-components.com/) & [Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction). Not to mention, CSS in JS also have many other benefits, such as could make your CSS reusable (It will be treaten like an object before turning to actual CSS), hope this can help you.